# Difficulties in reordering legend labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, legend

**Question:** how to relevel/reorder the legend? Preferably, I would like a solution in `dplyr`.

I have

[image]

I would like the legend to go `1 year`, `3 years` and `5 years`.

I tried adding `ggplot(df %>% mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("y_et", "y_tre", "y_fem)), (...)`; however, that led to a completely different plot.

Why would such approach not work?

```
  my_labels <- c("5 years",
                 "3 years",
                 "1 year")


  ggplot(df, aes(x=lnd, y = value, colour = name, group = name))  + 

  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=15),
                  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=15),
                  plot.subtitle=element_text(size=13, hjust=0.5)) + 

  ggtitle("Stage III - IV", subtitle="The predicted probability of death in:") +

    geom_area(aes(fill = name), position = "stack", alpha = 0.15) +
    geom_line(colour = "white", size = 3, position = "stack") +
    geom_line(position = "stack") +
    geom_point(position = "stack", data = df[c(1:3, -2:0 + nrow(df)), ], 
               shape=21, fill="white", stroke=1, size=3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#2C77BF", "#E38072", "#6DBCC3"),
                      labels = my_labels, name="") +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#2C77BF", "#E38072", "#6DBCC3"),
                        labels = my_labels, name="") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, .1),
                       labels = paste0(seq(0,100,10), "%"),
                       name="") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, 5), limits = c(0,5),
                       labels = paste0(seq(0, 5, 5), "%"),
                       name="")
```

My data

```
df <- structure(list(lnd = c(0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2, 2, 
2, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.9, 
2.9, 2.9, 3, 3, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.3), name = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("y_fem", "y_tre", "y_et"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.187647447225959, 0.336503915855623, 0.176173810718115, 
    0.18810776389886, 0.337006457876672, 0.176194262291169, 0.188569074126821, 
    0.33750867615062, 0.176213486223484, 0.189031379338693, 0.338010564380768, 
    0.176231478883057, 0.189494680961372, 0.338512116247097, 
    0.176248236654192, 0.189958980419767, 0.339013325406294, 
    0.176263755937716, 0.190424279136769, 0.339514185491777, 
    0.176278033151198, 0.190890578533225, 0.340014690113716, 
    0.176291064729166, 0.191357880027909, 0.340514832859065, 
    0.176302847123326, 0.191826185037491, 0.341014607291582, 
    0.176313376802783, 0.192295494976505, 0.341514006951863, 
    0.176322650254257, 0.192765811257325, 0.342013025357368, 
    0.176330663982311, 0.193237135290132, 0.342511656002451, 
    0.176337414509563, 0.193709468482881, 0.343009892358391, 
    0.176342898376914, 0.194182812241277, 0.343507727873425, 
    0.176347112143769, 0.194657167968742, 0.344005155972778, 
    0.176350052388258, 0.19513253706638, 0.344502170058699, 0.176351715707464, 
    0.195608920932955, 0.344998763510498, 0.176352098717641, 
    0.196086320964852, 0.345494929684576, 0.176351198054442, 
    0.196564738556054, 0.345990661914466, 0.176349010373143, 
    0.197044175098102, 0.34648595351087, 0.176345532348871, 0.197524631980071, 
    0.346980797761699, 0.176340760676825, 0.198006110588536, 
    0.347475187932109, 0.176334692072507, 0.198488612307541, 
    0.347969117264548, 0.176327323271947, 0.198972138518564, 
    0.348462578978791, 0.17631865103193, 0.199456690600491, 0.34895556627199, 
    0.176308672130226, 0.19994226992958, 0.349448072318712, 0.176297383365814, 
    0.200428877879429, 0.34994009027099, 0.176284781559118, 0.200916515820946, 
    0.350431613258362, 0.176270863552228, 0.201405185122314, 
    0.350922634387926, 0.176255626209135, 0.201894887148959, 
    0.351413146744385, 0.176239066415958, 0.202385623263518, 
    0.351903143390094, 0.176221181081177, 0.202877394825808, 
    0.352392617365113, 0.176201967135862, 0.203370203192787)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

**UPDATED**
The "completely different plot" looks like this.

```
  ggplot(df %>% mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("y_et", "y_tre", "y_fem"))), 
         aes(x=lnd, y = value, colour = name, group = name))  +
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious to see your "completely different plot".  The approach to reverse the levels is precisely what you have indicated (although the code in your question has a missing `"` and a missing `)`).  Alternatively, you can refactor before the plot (my preference) via `df$name <- factor(df$name, levels=c("y_et", "y_tre", "y_fem"))`.  It seems to work for me - the plot changes because the order of the levels defines the order of the plotting of those layers as well in the final plot (so the areas get stacked in reverse order too).

Comment: Please provide a definition of `my_labels`.

Comment: Please, see the updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `guide=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)` to the "scale_colour_manual" and "scale_fill_manual" statement.  This addition will change the order of the legend but without changing the order of the factors.